# When to make a function deferred using Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using the Q node library for Promises, question I think can apply to the Bluebird lib as well.

### Context

I have a few function calls to make to both my own custom functions and node.js `fs` style async functions.

if I'm making a call to a function like this:

> sync function

```
do_something = function (input) {
  // assign variables, do other sync stuff 
}
```

and need the above to take place `before` this function:

> sync function

```
do_something_else = function (input) {
  // assign variable, do other sync stuff
}
```

and `then` need to call a native node function similar to:

> async function

```
writeData = function (obj, callback) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  fs.writeFile(obj.file, obj.datas, function (err, result) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err);
    else deferred.resolve('write data completed');
  });
  return deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
}
```

and `finally` need the above to take place `before` this function:

> sync function

```
do_something_last = function (input) {
  // assign variable, do other sync stuff
}
```

### Question

Is the 'right' thing to do here, to make all my functions 'deferred' or promise aware so I can make sure that they are called in sequence or in the correct order?
like so:

```
do_something(variable)
.then(do_something_else)
.then(writeData)
.then(do_something_last)
.done();
```

or should I just do this instead and keep the ordering (sequencing)? Like so:

```
var variable1 = 'test1.txt'
var variable2 = 'test2.txt'
var return_value = do_something(variable1);
var return_another_value = do_something_else(return_value); <--sync
writeData(return_another_value); <-- async function
var final_value = do_something_last(variable2);  <-- sync function
// could potentially have async calls again after a sync call
writeDataAgain(return_another_value); <-- async function
```

### Clarifications

What I thought was since some of these sync functions are going to need to be fired after the async, I needed to make them Promise aware in order to keep the sequence straight, like so:

> sync functions made promise aware

```
do_something = function (input) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  // assign variables, do other sync stuff 
  deferred.resolve(_output_result_);
  return deferred.promise;
}
do_something_else = function (input) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  // assign variables, do other sync stuff 
  deferred.resolve(_output_result_);
  return deferred.promise;
}
do_something_last = function (input) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  // assign variables, do other sync stuff 
  deferred.resolve('completed workflow');
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

this would allow me to do this:

```
do_something(variable)
.then(do_something_else) <-- these need to execute before writeData
.then(writeData) <-- a async node fs call to writeFile
.then(do_something_last) <-- I need this to happen after the writeDate
.done();
```

After the feedback i've read, i guess what it seems like i'm really asking is:

> How do I create a function workflow, mixing non-promise sync and
>   promise-aware async function calls, all the while keeping the ordering
>   (or sequencing) of execution?

Comment: so your first two functions aren't asynchronous?

Comment: I updated my question with a Clarification section after reading the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just do this instead and keep the ordering like so:
>
> ```
> writeData(return_another_value);
> var final_value = do_something_last(variable2);
> ```

Well, that simply won't work, as `do_something_last` is not called after the `writeData(…)` promise is *resolved*. It'll just start right after the promise is created and returned. So if you care about that particular order and want to wait until the data is written, then you *need* to use `then` with a callback:

```
var final_promise = writeData(return_another_value).then(function(writeResult) {
    return do_something_last(variable2);
});
```

---

The general rules are:

- make synchronous functions synchronous - no need for promises
- make all asynchronous functions always return a promise
- use deferreds only at the lowest possible level for [promisification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

You can just place **synchronous functions in a `then` chain**, non-promise return values (or even thrown exceptions) work fine in them.
So while you *can* write your sequence like

```
Q('test1.txt')
.then(do_something)
.then(do_something_else)
.then(writeData)
.then(do_something_last.bind(null, 'test2.txt'))
.done();
```

it looks rather odd. If you don't plan to make the `do_something`s asynchronous in the near future for some reason, it's often simpler to write and read

```
writeData(do_something_else(do_something('test1.txt'))).then(function() {
    return do_something_last('test2.txt');
}).done();
```

Admittedly, it's sometimes more appealing to write

```
somePromise()
.then(doSomethingSynchronous)
.then(doSomethingAsynchronous)
```

than

```
somePromise
.then(function(res) { return doSomethingAsynchronous(doSomethingSynchronous(res)); })
```

even though they are **functionally identical**. Choose the style that you like better and that is more consistent.

Comment: thanks.  my issue I guess is something you point out in your bullet items.  I have a few sync calls and a few async calls to make.  but they are all related, and the order matters.  i'm basically building a workflow here.  so if there's a async call in the chain, the rest of the sync calls are going to have  to follow the async call to make sure they only fire after the async call has completed -- as far as I know.  so what I thought is that I would have to make the sync calls Promise aware to I can link they in the chain.

Comment: @Aaron: No, synchronous functions don't need to be promise-aware. Regardless of how you use them.

Comment: thanks again for the updated answer.  i'll go back and try out making my sync function non-promised and place them in the chain.  I'll update this post on what I find.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is whether your functions go in sequence or not, then do this:

```
do_something(variable)
.then(do_something_else)
.then(writeData)
.then(do_something_last)
.done();
```

You'd only assign promises to variables when you're going to be passing those variables around (e.g. to other services), or using them to create different promise chains.

e.g

```
var promise = do_something('123')

// two different promise chains

var task1 = promise.then(function(res){
  // logic
})

var task2 = promise.then(function(res){
  // other logic, independent from task1
})
```