# Javascript: Return a promise inside async function

Tags: javascript

Would it make any difference if I have:

```
async function test () {
  const foo = await bar()
  return Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
}
```

instead of:

```
async function test () {
  const foo = await bar()
  const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  // Given that I don't care about result1, result2 in this `test` function
  return [result1, result2]
}
```

I get the same result if I do either. E.g. I can do this for either case:

```
test().then(([result1, result2]) => { ... })
```

but I am more curious about the underlying mechanism how they both behave the same.

In other words, how does async function handle it if inside the function I return a promise instead of a value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're effectively calling synchronous-like functions with `await` within the promise chain which, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348311/244811):

> You are perfectly free to call either synchronous functions within the
>   promise chain (from within .then() handlers) or asynchronous functions
>   that then return a new promise.
>
> When you return something from a .then() handler, you can return
>   either a value (which becomes the resolved value of the parent
>   promise) or you can return another promise (which chains onto the
>   previous promise) or you can throw which works like returning a
>   rejected promise (the promise chain becomes rejected).

Answer (score 7):

I would think the way async functions works in respect to the return value is it checks whether that value is wrapped in a Promise object, and if not, does it automatically. If you explicitly return a Promise, then the function does nothing with it. I tested this out by returning a new Promise inside an async function:

```
async function test(){
var duration = resolveAfter(500)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{})
}

var neverresolved = test()
```

The result is neverresolved contains a Promise that's always in the pending state, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Both functions return a `Promise`.

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
//HERE
return [result1, result2]
```

Where I wrote HERE you can access to result1 and result2 var that are the results of the promises.

await is an alternative to call `then` on `Promise` and its form is also more readable than

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(results){

});
```

If you have multiple sequentially requests using await is a better choice

```
var response1= await promise1   
var response2=await promise2
```

against

```
promise1.then(function(){
    promise2.then(function(){
       promise3.then(function(){
       })
    })
})
```

EDIT

In the first function the keyword  async is useless, the function test will return a Promise

The second function will return a Promise where you see the keyword await. When the awaited promise will resolved the execution inside the function continue and you can access to result of the promise

EDIT 1

MaybeI understand what you mean, the async keyword encapsulate your return value into a promise that has as resolved value what you have returned

Comment: Yep, I understand that. However, if saying async always returns a promise, it means it will wrap the returned promise inside another promise?

Comment: Promise.all create a new promise that is the same that will return,

await will simply pause the execution of the function until the value from the promise is available.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know about Promise.all, and how to use async functions. My question is more like: with the first case, I return a value which the async function would resolve to. As for the second case, what exactly happens?

Comment: Not really what I'm asking. It looks useless because I gave a simple example, what if in between, I need to do an `await`? then the `async` won't be useless.

Comment: The async became useless if you not use await inside

Comment: The example can easily be changed to something that has a few awaits inside and not really the point of my question. How does async function handle it when inside, I return a promise instead a value?

Comment: If you simply return a promise,the async do nothing. Async only works in union with await in the same way await can works only with async

Comment: Please see the updated examples, there are other awaits inside the function.